# .each_line do printing the contents of the variable twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text, line, each, record

The following code prints out each individual line text column of a record in a database and prints it in HAML.

```
= @record.description.each_line do |line|
        - i += 1
        .line
            %span= i
            %li= line
```

For whatever reason it prints every individual line next to its line number like you'd expect but then also prints it as one continuous string outside of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using HAML. The `=` operator outputs content to the template, which is why each line appears inside an `<li>`:

```
%li= line
```

Using the equals operator with `each_line` will cause the return value of `each_line` to output to the template. This is why you see the entire contents as one continuous line.

Change this line

```
= @record.description.each_line do |line|
```

to

```
- @record.description.each_line do |line|
```

and you should get the result you want.